# Why doesn't println! work in Rust unit tests?

Tags: rust, println

I've implemented the following method and unit test:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn read_file(path: &Path) {
    let mut file = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents).unwrap();
    println!("{contents}");
}

#[test]
fn test_read_file() {
    let path = &Path::new("/etc/hosts");
    println!("{path:?}");
    read_file(path);
}
```

I run the unit test this way:

```
rustc --test app.rs; ./app
```

I could also run this with

```
cargo test
```

I get a message back saying the test passed but the `println!` is never displayed on screen. Why not?

Comment: Finding this unintuitive, I've opened [Issue #10777 on GitHub to suggest changing this behavior](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10777#issue-1277499859)

Answer (score 704, accepted):

This happens because Rust test programs hide the stdout of successful tests in order for the test output to be tidy. You can disable this behavior by passing the `--nocapture` option to the test binary or to `cargo test` (but, in this case *after* `--` – see below):

```
#[test]
fn test() {
    println!("Hidden output")
}
```

Invoking tests:

```
% rustc --test main.rs; ./main

running 1 test
test test ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured

% ./main --nocapture

running 1 test
Hidden output
test test ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured

% cargo test -- --nocapture

running 1 test
Hidden output
test test ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured
```

If tests fail, however, their stdout will be printed regardless if this option is present or not.

Comment: You mentioned passing the `--nocapture` option to `cargo test`, but cargo does not recognize this flag for me (using the latest nightly from rustup.sh).  Are you sure it should work?

Comment: @JimGarrison, indeed, [there is an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/296) on that. Meanwhile you can use `cargo test -- --nocapture`, it should work.

Comment: thanks!  unrelated to this question, but that also helped me figure out how to get `cargo test [--] --bench` to work too!

Comment: `cargo test -- --no-capture` no longer works. I get the following error: `thread '<main>' panicked at '"Unrecognized option: \'no-capture\'."', ../src/libtest/lib.rs:249`

Comment: @Nashenas, the option is called `nocapture`, not `no-capture`.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to print when debugging in Visual Studio Code in windows? The following task does not print to the popup shell: "cargo test --no-run -- --nocapture" debugger. Note the use of the no-run argument although it does not seem to make a difference either way. All I see is "running 1 test". Awkward tooling.

Comment: Its recommended to use `--package` and `--exact` flag if you have a big code base `cargo test --package <package_name> <file_name>::<mod_name>::<test_name> -- --nocapture --exact`.

Comment: @Anonyme2000 `--nocapture` still works in the 2018 edition.  `--show-output` is another option that organizes the output in a format that is easier to see.

Answer (score 176):

TL;DR

```
$ cargo test -- --nocapture
```

With the following code:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum PieceShape {
    King, Queen, Rook, Bishop, Knight, Pawn
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

#[test]
fn demo_debug_format() {
    let q = PieceShape::Queen;
    let p = PieceShape::Pawn;
    let k = PieceShape::King;
    println!("q={:?} p={:?} k={:?}", q, p, k);
}
```

Then run the following:

```
 $ cargo test -- --nocapture
```

And you should see

```
Running target/debug/chess-5d475d8baa0176e4

running 1 test
q=Queen p=Pawn k=King
test demo_debug_format ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured
```

Comment: `cargo test -- --no-capture` no longer works. I get the following error: `thread '<main>' panicked at '"Unrecognized option: \'no-capture\'."', ../src/libtest/lib.rs:249`

Comment: I wonder if this issue https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1377 is the problem?

Comment: As has been pointed out in previous comments, the option is `--nocapture`, not `--no-capture`. However, that's a completely obvious mistake to make given most command line conventions we tend to come across. I just used this option exactly as described in this answer in rust 1.1 (cargo 0.2.0) and it worked exactly as advertised.

Answer (score 71):

Preface: This answer reflects a change in **Rust 1.41** ("You can now pass `--show-output` argument to test binaries to print the output of successful tests." per the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/92009f217a05d12716e278b4ade8d2624946eb5f/RELEASES.md#compiler-33))

---

As [mentioned by L. F.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106554/why-doesnt-println-work-in-rust-unit-tests#comment112936943_25107081), `--show-output` is the way to go.

```
$ cargo test -- --show-output
```

Other display flags are [mentioned in the documentation of cargo test in display-options](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html#display-options).

Comment: **Note**: `--show-output` only prints stdout of **successful** tests.

Comment: This was helpful.  The odd extra -- on the CL confused me. 
I needed to run just one test & show output.  That looks like

$ cargo test [test_name] -- --show-output

Comment: Yeah, the odd extra `--` is to control that the next arguments are passed to `cargo test`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @zingi that is not true. According on [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-02-running-tests.html) it shows output of **failed** tests too.

Comment: I've just tested it. And indeed it looks like this has changed. `--show-output` prints stdout of successful and failed tests now ( v1.68.2)

Comment: Currently, failed tests print their output regardless of this flag

Answer (score 27):

To include print outs with `println!()` and keep colors for the test results, use the `color` and `nocapture` flags in `cargo test`.

```
$ cargo test -- --color always --nocapture
```

(cargo version: 0.13.0 nightly)

Answer (score 13):

While testing, standard output is not displayed. Don't use text messages for testing but `assert!`, `assert_eq!`, and `fail!` instead. Rust's unit test system can understand these but not text messages.

The test you have written will pass even if something goes wrong. Let's see why:

`read_to_end`'s signature is 
`fn read_to_end(&mut self) -> IoResult<Vec<u8>>`

It returns an `IoResult` to indicate success or error. This is just a type def for a `Result` whose error value is an `IoError`. It's up to you to decide how an error should be handled. In this case, we want the task to fail, which is done by calling `unwrap` on the `Result`.

This will work:

```
let contents = File::open(&Path::new("message.txt"))
    .read_to_end()
    .unwrap();
```

`unwrap` should not be overused though.

Comment: True information, but not an answer to OP.

Comment: I think this is Rust's way to prevent us from shooting yourself in the foot. Second form of assert is exactly what logging should do, but another way around. Instead of painstakingly write 10K+ logs when all OK, write when something is NOT. `std::module_path` macro may be useful too.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the modern solution (`cargo test -- --show-output`) doesn't work in doctests defined in a Markdown code-fence in the docstring of your functions. Only `println!` (etc.) statements done in a concrete `#[test]` block will be respected.

Answer (score 5):

It's likely that the test output is being captured by the testing framework and not being printed to the standard output. When running tests with cargo test, the output of each test is captured and displayed only if the test fails. If you want to see the output of a test, you can use the --nocapture flag when running the test with cargo test. Like so:

```
cargo test -- --nocapture
```

Or you can use the println! macro inside a test function to print output to the standard output. Like so:

```
 #[test]
 fn test_read_file() {
    let path = &Path::new("/etc/hosts");
    println!("{:?}", path);
    read_file(path);
    println!("The test passed!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to run the test displaying the printed output everytime the file changes:

```
cargo watch -x "test -- --nocapture"
```

Comment: It would be better for this answer to drop the mention of `sudo` since it is an orthogonal concern,  unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Why? I don't know, but there is a small hack `eprintln!("will print in {}", "tests")`

Comment: `eprintln!()` does not work for me for successful tests (cargo/rustc 1.69.0 (2023-04-12))

Comment: No; `cargo test` captures both stdout and stderr by default (when all tests pass).