Is there a way to sleep only with futures crate?
Apparently, sleeping is hard as it's not on the futures crate, or maybe it is too specific for the operating system wake mechanism for sleeping.
I'm trying to keep my dependencies count low, and I need just sleep for approximately 1 second, it does not need to be exact. Is there some kind of hack that I can do without adding one more crate to the project?
My try:
use futures::channel::oneshot;
use std::thread;

#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
pub async fn async_delay(duration: std::time::Duration) -> Result<(), ()> {
    let (tx, rx) = oneshot::channel();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        std::thread::sleep(duration);
        //TODO: treat error?
        tx.send(()).map_err(|_| ())
    });

    rx.await.map_err(|_| ())?;
    Ok(())
}



#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use futures::executor::block_on;

    #[test]
    fn test_async_delay() {
        println!("a");
        block_on(async {
            println!("begin");
            loop {
                println!("start delay");
                async_delay(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1))
                    .await
                    .unwrap();
            }
        });
    }
}


The simplest hack would be to write a future that spawns a thread and does the sleeping there, though obviously this has the overhead of creating a thread. You don't specify what performance characteristics are acceptable so I don't know if this would work for you. Many runtimes have a mechanism to sleep, though -- which runtime are you using?

Sleeping isn't hard, it's just that it's something that it's the scheduler's responsability.

@jthulhu futures contains a single-threaded executor, so I would argue that a sleep functionality wouldn't be completely misplaced in this crate.

@cdhowie how to launch a thread in the futures crate?

@GuerlandoOCs std::thread::spawn

@cdhowie take a look at my updated answer or https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b97137236714f30573efe1a1d5fae0cc it does not work

@GuerlandoOCs It is, in fact, working. https://stackoverflow.com/q/25106554/501250
